# In risc-v architecture, how does store conditional instruction realize that the memory is modified?

Tags: assembly, atomic, cpu-architecture, riscv, load-link-store-conditional

The following code snippet is from [Computer Organization and Design, RISC-V edition, 2nd edition](https://www.elsevier.com/books/computer-organization-and-design-risc-v-edition/patterson/978-0-12-820331-6).

Suppose that the memory location that is addressed by `x20` register is modified after execution of `lr.w` instruction and before execution of `sc.w`. My Question is that how does the `sc.w` instruction realize that the content of the memory location is changed.

```
again:
lr.w x10, (x20)       // load-reserved
sc.w x11, x23, (x20)  // store-conditional
bne x11, x0, again    // branch if store fails (0)
addi x23, x10, 0      // put loaded value in x23
```

Comment: Ideally, the `lr` instruction performs the load and put the address used in a  CAM (read: hash table) of watched address. The CPU snoops memory traffic and if any hit a target in that CAM a corresponding flag is set. The `sc` most likely only checks that flag.

Comment: Probably by tracking MESI cache invalidation for the cache line containing that word, with the `lr.w` "arming the monitor".  (ARM CPUs have equivalent instructions, and the documentation of the internals calls it a "monitor".)  It doesn't actually check for modification, it just has to check that it kept the cache line in Modified or Exclusive state since the `lr.w`.  (That's why C++ has `compare_exchange_weak` which can be non-looping, exposing the "spurious failures" when LL/SC wasn't sure even though the data wasn't actually modified.)